# How to monitor threads' memory usage in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

For a scheduling requirement, I need to measure the memory bandwidth that each process/thread is utilizing in the Linux kernel.

Is there such a feature already implemented in the kernel? If not, I appreciate any solution on how may I monitor this bandwidth usage (per thread/process) in the kernel?

Please note that I need to monitor this in kernel space, not user space.

Comment: There are perf counters that meausre memory loads and stores.

Comment: to use ther perf counters you can use the perf utility. There besides the cpu counter there will be counters associated with cache misses. the tool will report the thread and function of the nth miss

Comment: Thanks. How to read perf counters in the kernel or a kernel module? @stark

Comment: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Well, this is the userspace tool, but how to use the counters in the kernel source? @stark

Comment: Applications that process data run in userpace. The kernel provides access to system resources.

Comment: Sure, but considering my question, I'm developing a scheduler in kernel. @stark